# How to inform the user they have been logged out from their previous account when logging in to a new account in a new tab

Tags: login, signup-signon, logout, flow

We have multiple products that belong together, a suite of products. They all share a single-sign-on solution ie users can log in to one of the products and are automatically logged in to all of the other products they might have access too. Users can only be logged in to one account at a time ie if they have an active session and go to any of the products log in pages they are automatically re-directed to the products dashboards.

Users can be invited to use these products. Upon invitation, they have to create an account. As soon as they create their account they are logged in to the product. The flow is like this:

User receives invitation email > User clicks accept invitation > User sees a create account screen in their browser > User enters their name and password and clicks "create profile" > The user is logged in to the product.

Now, imagine a user has an account and is logged in using email-1. They now receive an invitation for email-2. They accept the invitation. The create profile view is opened in a new tab in their browser. When they click "create profile" they are logged in to the product with email-2. Their previous login for email-1 is ended and they are automatically logged out from that account.

What should the user see when they go to that tab? What is a good message?

We're thinking a modal with a message saying they have been logged out due to the fact they logged in with a new account. They will also get two options:
1) Continue with email-2. This basically refreshes the window, close the modal and they are now in their email-2 account.
2) Log back in with email-1. This logs them out from all accounts and they are taken to the product login view. In this case if the user goes to their second tab they see the same modal and message but for the other account.

Thoughts?

Comment: Both seems to deliver a bad experience, why dont you allow cross Tab Sessions?

Comment: Imagine you would use Google Excel Sheets and on a other Tab you wanna use Google Docs but it logs you out because you already have the Excel Sheets open, bad UX

Comment: There is no way right now for us to allow a user to be logged in to two different accounts in two different tabs in the same browser.

Comment: Then I guess you just have to get out the most of the situation you can but In my  neutral User opinion I wouldnt enjoy that behaviour of being only logged in in one tab, what I dont get i thought you use one acc for the different tabs?

Comment: It's all part of a single sign-on solution, meaning that you can only be logged in to one account at a time. As soon as you try to go to the login view to log in to a different account you will be automatically directed to the product dashboard. The only way to switch account is to first log out.

Comment: Yes but if its only one Account why is it restricted to one tab :o

Comment: Its not only one account tho :D Here is the part that is makes this tricky:

"Now, imagine a user has an account and is logged in using email-1. They now receive an invitation for email-2. They accept the invitation. The create profile view is opened in a new tab in their browser. When they click "create profile" they are logged in to the product with email-2. Their previous login for email-1 is ended and they are automatically logged out from that account."

Answer (score 1):

**Communicate what has happened.**

It's a great solution to offer options like you mentioned before -

- Continue using your new account.
- Logout of your new account and return to your previous account.

Here's two sources to help you out further.

[Do not add too many options](https://www.nngroup.com/videos/choice-overload-harms-users/) and [be clear what your options are.](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/explicit-differences/)

This is a long shot, but maybe have an option to merge your e-mail addresses into the same account for your product suite. It's common to have one account with multiple ways of loggin in. You might even have multiple ways of logging in to the account you're writing your question with.

Long story short...good thinking. I like your modal solution.